# illegal use of this type as expression (error) C++

Tags: c++, types

The most recent file I've added to my VC++ 2010 project is suddenly giving me errors about the data types. 
After doing a bit of searching, this error seems to be common in C code but I'm using C++ (and yes, my file extension is correct).
My BUFFER class still works fine in all my other files and if I comment those out, it throws the same errors about the windows UINT types as well.

Btw, this is from "DRONEPOOL.h"

my code:

```
//#include <winsock2.h>
//#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include "BUFFER.h"

#ifndef __DRONEPOOL_H__
#define __DRONEPOOL_H__

#define DRONE_POOL_SIZE 100

#define DRONESTATE_EMPTY   0
#define DRONESTATE_IDLE    1
#define DRONESTATE_WORKING 2
#define DRONESTATE_PICKUP  3   // work result ready for pickup

#define LPCLIENTCONNECTION CLIENTCONNECTION*
struct CLIENTCONNECTION
{
//  SOCKET skSocket;
    WORD   wState;
};


#define LPDRONEPOOL DRONEPOOL*
class DRONEPOOL
{
pritave:
    BUFFER bfTaskBuffer;
    BUFFER bfResultBuffer;
    CLIENTCONNECTION ccPool[DRONE_POOL_SIZE];
    UINT iPoolHead;
    UINT iPoolTail;
    HANDLE hPoolMutex;
    HANDLE hManagerThread;
    static DWORD WINAPI Manager(__in LPVOID);
public:
    DRONEPOOL();
    ~DRONEPOOL();
    BOOL InsertDrone(SOCKET);
    BOOL AssignTask(LPXMSG);
    BOOL PeekResult(LPXMSG);
    BOOL GetResult(LPXMSG);
};

#endif
```

The error is: ERROR C2275: 'BUFFER' : Illegal use of this type as expression

Any idea how to resolve this problem?

Comment: could you point which line gives you an error?

Comment: When you say `#define LPCLIENTCONNECTION CLIENTCONNECTION*` , don't you mean `typedef LPCLIENTCONNECTION CLIENTCONNECTION*;`

Comment: C and C++ have this nifty keyword `typedef`.  Don't use macros to declare names for pointer types.

Comment: @karl: That's backwards.

Comment: As KarlPhillip is alluding to, in C++ you should stop using #define and start using typedef.

Comment: You shouldn't use reserved names for the include guard - remove the underscores from the beginning.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most likely the misspelled `private` is confusing the compiler on the next line where your `BUFFER bfTaskBuffer` is declared.

EDIT:
Also a few comments about the code and style:

- Double underscores are reserved in any context, and leading underscores are some contexts (followed by capital letter or in the global namespace, maybe others). Just use `DRONEPOOL_H`.
- Typically all caps is reserved for constants. Consider `Dronepool` instead of `DRONEPOOL`.
- Instead of using `#define` for the pointer alias, use typedef: *After* the class definition do `typedef DRONEPOOL* LPDRONEPOOL;` which creates a type alias, not text substitution.

Comment: Didn't see your answered lying there. Yes, he has a typo: `pritave`

Comment: rotfl, You'd think they could have come up with an error message for that XD

Comment: How would the compiler know you've misspelt a keyword, and it's not just an unresolved type?

Comment: @Mark Ingram  I'd assume by how it's being used in a scope controller syntax

Comment: Remember that `:` also starts a label in some contexts though. Probably enough to confuse the compiler.

Comment: @Mark B: more relevant here, it's also used for bitfields in class definitions.

Comment: Using typedefs for pointer types is arguably a bad idea -- though it's better than using `#define`. But it's a pervasive practice in Windows.